# Creating what-if's in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

Data tables in Excel are really nice to see how numbers would evolve if one of your input changes. However:

- they're (very) slow
- the variable you edit is not dynamic; i.e. changing the row or column input cell to `=INDIRECT(<dynamic address>)` works but doesn't update if the dynamic adress changes.
- they force you to use an annoying structure
- the variable needs to be in the same sheet as the table

Because I want to do a lot of them, point 1 and 2 make it very impractical to work with data tables. Is there any way to make a function that does this in VBA? I tried a UDF that changes the variable's value (e.g. `=whatif(<hypothetical output>, <variable cell>, <variable hypothetical value>)`, but that's not allowed in VBA (see [How to prevent VBA function from re-executing inside the code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19825088/how-to-prevent-vba-function-from-re-executing-inside-the-code)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am quite sure you can achieve your goals using subs rather than UDFs.  The concept is to, basically, treat the worksheet like one huge function:

1. the sub sets up a group of input cells
2. the sub allows the worksheet to calculate
3. the sub monitors the output cell(s)

If the goal is some kind of non-linear analysis (like sensitivity analysis), the sub compares successive runs.  If the goal is some kind of optimization, the sub drives the inputs to achieve a result.  If the goal is some kind of statistical analysis or modelling, the sub can drive a Monti Carlo.

Comment: I ended up doing it with subs indeed, and copy pasting values the output